# implement a template function for container's elements sum by C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, sum

I am implementing the Reduce function using templates. The 
Reduce fn applies a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of 
an STL container, from begin() to end(), so as to reduce the sequence to a 
single value.

```
 For example, Reduce(<list containing 1,2,3,4,5>, std::plus<int>()) should calculate ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)

class NotEnoughElements {};

template <typename Container, typename Function>
typename Container::value_type
Reduce(const Container& c, Function fn) throw (NotEnoughElements)
{
   FILL HERE (recursion)
}
```

My C++ code:

```
Reduce(const Container& c, Function fn) throw (NotEnoughElements)
{
    if (c.begin() == c.end() || c.size() < 1)
            throw(NotEnoughElements);
    Container::iterator itr = c.begin(); 
    Container::iterator itr_end = c.end(); 
    Container::value_type  sum = 0;
    Fn(itr, itr_end, sum);
    Return sum;
}

void Fn(Container::const_iterator itr,  Container::const_iterator itr_end, Container::value_type& sum)
{
  sum += *itr;
  if (itr == itr_end || itr+1 == itr_end)
     return ;
  Fn(++itr, itr_end, sum);

}
```

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Recursion is usually a bad idea in C++, especially when (as here) iteration is trivial. And did you have a question?

Comment: Can't you just use `std::accumulate`?

Comment: Typically, reductions don't throw when they have not enough elements, they are seeded with a start value (typically 0) and just return that. To Mike's point, the reason to avoid recursion is that for long lists you'll get...STACK OVERFLOW.

Comment: Drop that 'throw (NotEnoughElements)' !!!

Answer (score 2):

First let me just observe: Don't use exception specifications. They're deprecated in C++11 anyway.

I would suggest using `accumulate` to do the work (and do *strongly* consider using a two iterator `Reduce` rather than one taking a container):

```
Reduce(const Container& c, Function fn) throw (NotEnoughElements)
{
    return std::accumulate(c.begin(), c.end(), typename Container::value_type());
}
```

Comment: Personally, I like container based algorithms, especially ones that can support sub-ranges of containers if needed (which is almost all of them).  The common case is a full container: the special case just requires a bit of glue.  If you can write an interface that makes the usual case cleaner, but requires the extra glue in the rare case, that seems like a better interface than the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented `Reduce` like follows:

```
template <typename Function, typename Container>
typename Container::value_type
Reduce(Function reducefn, Container list)
{
    return std::accumulate(begin(list), end(list),
                           typename Container::value_type(), reducefn);
}

template <typename Function, typename Container>
typename Container::value_type
Reduce(Function reducefn, Container list,
       typename Container::value_type initial)
{
    return std::accumulate(begin(list), end(list), initial, reducefn);
}
```

For your reference.